# layout-land Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0b007b

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I am tring to do horizontal layout implementation but layout's in layout-land are not get called. I tried near about all solutions given online.

> I am getting Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0b007b

on

```
setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);
```

when there is only horizontal layout of that activity. (I tried by keeping only one layout of that activity in layout-land)

In Manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.Login"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize"   />
```

My layout-land folder is in res folder, so there is no issue of it.
I Cleaned project restart Studio delete "build" folder but nothing worked for me.

Below method also doesn't gets called:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    Log.d(TAG, "onConfigurationChanged()             " + newConfig.orientation);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) 
        {
//myCode
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
//myCode
    }
}
```

Horizontal Works only when if i press android device menu button all applications able to see in horizontal mode and when i click on my application it get's horizontal and after that it works in both views horizontal as well as portrait view.

> onConfigurationChanged method get's called of that activity.

I don't understand why this is happening with my application.

Logs i get when application gets crash

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: com.my.pakage, PID: 6922
                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.pakage/com.my.pakage.activities.Login}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0b007b
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                                   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0b007b
                                                                      at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:195)
                                                                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2133)
                                                                      at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1142)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                      at com.my.pakage.activities.Login.onCreate(Login.java:96)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: looking at the error it seems like you are giving the wrong name or Id to access your widget or layout.

Comment: can you write down whole code

Comment: @Umair Horizontal Works only when if i press android device menu button all applications able to see in horizontal mode and when i click on my application it get's horizontal and after that it works in both views horizontal as well as portrait view. 

Then why these is happening ?

Comment: @Vishalkumarsinghvi which part of code ? cause it is happening with whole application so now i am tring to make one activity in horizontal mode to track the issue.

Comment: share you error logs ,and check your xml name in R.layout.xml_name

Comment: @ULHASPATIL the problem I believe is when you start your app in portrait mode android is not able to find the resource in portrait so it crashes. But if you start in landscape mode it finds the resource and it keeps working. Try adding the same land-layout in simple layout folder and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

> Handling the configuration change yourself can make it much more
>   difficult to use alternative resources, because the system does not
>   automatically apply them for you. This technique should be considered
>   a last resort when you must avoid restarts due to a configuration
>   change and is not recommended for most applications.

At first set

- **android:configChanges="orientation"**

**DEMO**

```
<activity android:name=".activities.Login"
          android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" 
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Read [**`Handle configuration changes`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes)

> When you declare your activity to handle a configuration
>   change, you are responsible for resetting any elements for which you
>   provide alternatives. If you declare your activity to handle the
>   orientation change and have images that should change between
>   landscape and portrait, you must re-assign each resource to each
>   element during [**`onConfigurationChanged()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onconfigurationchanged).

***FYI***

[**`Resources$NotFoundException`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.NotFoundException) exception is thrown by the resource APIs when a requested resource can not be found.